# MySQL Query Browser Tool and UTF 8 data Bug (?)

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

Does anyone know if theres a bug on **MySQL Query Browser tool** for UTF 8 insert?

if i do:

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('Hellá');
```

I got the ('Hell�') string in the browser.

That happens **only** with data inserted into DB via MySQL Query Browser Tool.

**Note:** Using Ajax/PHP on Apache 2.2 server with those config for PHP

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And html set to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN' http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'>
```

with:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Also in the FireFox properties for the page its fully UTF8.

Also the page was constructed using NotePad++ already codified in UTF8.

And... data inserted via Ajax is ok.

So.... what i'm missing...???

Best Regards.

**EDIT:**

Table charset UTF8 and
Table collation UTF8_general_ci.

also for gods sake... in my.ini:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html probably the client's charset is not utf8

Comment: Checked with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';` all set to utf8 but characer_set_filesystem wich is set to binary.

Comment: The subject line does not match the question...

Comment: Sorry Klas, the first time i've posted with wrong title/subject.

Comment: show variables is run at the CLI ? do you explicitly set the character set in PHP (mysql_set_charset or equivalent)

Comment: ajreal please post your comment as answer since it's correct. The last of the last is also to set `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` after the connection is estabilished. Thanks!!! `$con = mysql_connect("x.x.x.x", "user", "pass");
 mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the character set in PHP using mysql_set_charset or equivalent method/function